# How can I convert object keys & values to formatted string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I need to get the 'keys' as one string, and then their values as another.

Here's my failed attempt at writing this loop, it only really works on one level...

```
function convertToString(objArray) {
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in objArray[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','

            line += objArray[i][index];
        }

        str += line + '\r\n';
    }

    return str;
}
```

Here's an example object, the real one is much bigger, but this should do for example purposes:

```
var obj = {
    "a": "a",
        "b": [{
        "c": "c",
            "d": "d"
    }, {
        "e": "e",
            "f": "f"
    }],
    "g": true,
    "h": {
        "i": "i",
        "j": "j",
        "k": 1
    },
    "l": "l"
};
```

My desired output for the ***keys*** would be:

```
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"
```

And their respective values ***string*** would look like:

```
"a", object, "c", "d", "e", "f", true, object, "i", "j", 1, "l"
```

If someone could steer me in the right direction, that would be great, I don't expect anyone to write the code for me, but something to start me off would be great.

The purpose behind this, is so I can convert my response object to a format the I can use to download a CSV file of the same data.

Comment: So you want to collapse the structure?

Comment: @EvanKnowles in a sense yes!

Comment: What's point of doing this?

Comment: I want to send this data to a csv, basically I need to convert my response to a readable format to download a csv containing the same information. @undefined

Comment: Why is this being marked down? If you're marking it down, please tell me why.

Comment: Why is this off-topic? I really don't understand that....

Comment: This question was closed because you didn't show any attempts to solve it yourself, the close reason includes "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." It's a shame nobody bothered to actually comment when voting to close, but there you go. If you can try to at least show some of your own approach that might help a lot.

Comment: I didn't know that, I thought that posting too much, people don't read it, so I didn't include my failed code, instead I foccussed on what I'm trying to achieve, I also stated in the post that I didn't want anyone to write it for me, I just wanted a direction :( I have edited my question with my failed code, I hope that this can help it reopen... @StephanMuller, thankyou for letting me know why though!

Comment: StackOverflow is probably one of the few communities where TL;DR hardly ever applies. The more info, the better we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive for..in in javascript, like this:

http://jsbin.com/udEBAxe/2/edit

```
var obj = {
    "a": "a",
        "b": [{
        "c": "c",
            "d": "d"
    }, {
        "e": "e",
            "f": "f"
    }],
    "g": true,
    "h": {
        "i": "i",
        "j": "j",
        "k": 1
    },
    "l": "l"
};

function inspect(o, props){
  var kk = [];
  for(var p in o) {
    if(o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {      
      if(typeof o[p] == 'object')
        kk = kk.concat(inspect(o[p], props));
      else {
        var m = (props) ? o[p] : p;
        kk.push(m);
      }
    }
  }
  return kk;
}

var s = inspect(obj,false);
alert(s.join(','));

s = inspect(obj,true);
alert(s.join(','));
```

Comment: I marked this one as correct, You've achieved exactly what I'm after, in very minimal code, and even formatted the string. Thankyou very much.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/vUnF9/844/ Here's your awesome work in effect with my main object :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var obj = {
    "a": "a",
        "b": [{
        "c": "c",
            "d": "d"
    }, {
        "e": "e",
            "f": "f"
    }],
        "g": true,
        "h": {
        "i": "i",
            "j": "j",
            "k": 1
    },
        "l": "l"
};

function x(obj, keys, vals) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var val = obj[key];
            keys.push(key);
            vals.push(val);
            if (typeof val == 'object') {
                //borrowed from angularjs isArray
                //http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js
                if (toString.apply(val) == '[object Array]') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                        x(val[i], keys, vals)
                    }
                } else {
                    x(val, keys, vals)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var keys = [],
    vals = [];
x(obj, keys, vals);
console.log(keys)
console.log(vals)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/69enZ/)

Comment: You're a legend. That's exactly what I'm after!

Comment: This actually appears to be slightly off with my larger scale example, http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/vUnF9/842/

Notice that ID does not match the third key, for some reason, there's an object on the third key too, do you know why?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins it looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/69enZ/7/ ... the text representation looks like a problem because since you have an array as the result.. it will be printed as "Object, Object"

Comment: When converting this to a string format, see my example, the key's vs values don't align correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your output show you the value, not the keys of your objects.

You can simply get all keys with underscore.js library. This is the example for top level only :

```
_.keys(obj);
// output : [ "a","b","g","h","l" ];
```

And the doc : http://underscorejs.org/#keys

Comment: Thankyou, but I did state I need all levels in my example

Comment: I just gave the way to forward

Comment: I need both the keys and values, not just one, thankyou anyway.